# Required parameter 'tag' is missing PHP

Tags: php, android, android-volley

i get this error Required parameter 'tag' is missing on android toast  please help ,me i can't find my fault below i have android user code and the php server code above i use volley library for httprequests

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
        hideDialog();
        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
            if (!error) {
                // User successfully stored in MySQL
                // Now store the user in sqlite
                String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String email = user.getString("email");
                String created_at = user
                        .getString("created_at");

                // Inserting row in users table
                db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                // Launch login activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RegisterActivity.this,
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else {

                // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                // message
                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        hideDialog();
    }
})
{

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        // Posting params to register url
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("tag", "register");
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", password);

        return params;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
};

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

}

*AppcontrollerClass here*

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

this is android log

```
  08-07 14:35:36.552  19120-20088/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp D/Volley﹕ [7445] BasicNetwork.logSlowRequests: HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://192.168.1.3/android_login_api/ 0x355f917 NORMAL 1> [lifetime=3858], [size=65], [rc=200], [retryCount=0]
08-07 14:35:36.662  19120-19120/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp D/RegisterActivity﹕ Register Response: {"error":true,"error_msg":"Required parameter 'tag' is missing!"}
08-07 14:35:36.702  19120-19120/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp D/Toast﹕ checkMirrorLinkEnabled returns : false
08-07 14:35:36.702  19120-19120/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp D/Toast﹕ showing allowed
08-07 14:35:36.702  19120-19120/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp D/Volley﹕ [1] Request.finish: 4253 ms: [ ] http://192.168.1.3/android_login_api/ 0x355f917 NORMAL 1
08-07 14:35:36.712  19120-19120/com.example.panos.chatsmartapp E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

this is php code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "error" => FALSE);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} 
else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 'tag' is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

Myabe i have problem with utf8 string using json_encode/json_decode I do not know...

Comment: Without seeing the code that sends user to the server, it would be hard to tell what is wrong.  Can you look at log out put of what is sent to server?

Comment: i think that i  have all the code requirements  can you check it again

Comment: You can output file_get_contents('php://input') in php to get the raw data sent.  Looking at java code looks right to me compared to other code samples, but I have never used Volley, we use a library called Retrofit.  HTTP response for request=<[ ] http://192.168.1.3........ in log, do the empty brackets mean no data is being sent?

Comment: tag value is not sending i got this message "only Required parameter 'tag' is missing! " which i had it in else{} statement

Comment: Check your java code. Use HttpPost and response method with namevaluepair.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is create a html form with post method and try to hit the URL.If the response is correct it will mean that the FORM submission through POST call in your android code is incorrect.

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form" action="index.php" method="post">
<input name="name" type="tezt" value="Porcupine"/>
<input name="tag" type="hidden" value="register"/>
<input name="email" type="text" value="Porcupine@gmail.com"/>
<input name="password" type="password" value=""/>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
</body>
```

You can use this.Do replace the action URL accordingly

Comment: thank you i figured out my problem was at the php code, it was so simple to use the form submission post that i feel like idiot that don't think it

Comment: no problem.Anyone trying to find a solution will be benefitted now. (y)

Answer (score 0):

remove the code below don't  need

```
 @Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return headers;
}
```